# Update DIV content after AJAX post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

We have a div structure as below:

```
<!-- main.php starts -->
    <div class="main">
      <div class="one">
         <span class="buttonEdit">EDIT</span>
      </div>
      <div class="two">Content</div>
      <div class="editBox">
       <!-- abc.php which is loaded onClick -->
        <textarea class="editArea"></textarea>
        <span class="buttonSave">SAVE</span>
       <!--abc.php ends -->
      </div>
    </div>
<!-- main.php ends -->
```

The jQuery I used is this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
        //SAVE BUTTON
        $(".buttonSave").click(function(){
            //AJAX SAVE HERE
            $.post("save.php",function(msg){
                var newContent;
                newContent = $(".editArea").val();

                $(this).parents(".main").find('.two').text(newContent);
             });
        });
```

**The Process:**
On clicking the EDIT button, an external page(*abc.php*) will load to div(*class="editBox"*) via jQuery's load function.
After Editing and Saving, the content from the textarea must be displayed in the div(*class="two"*).

**IMPORTANT** There are several Similar blocks and the class names are same. The jQuery is written in *abc.php* which is an external file. Is it possible to use 'find' and 'this' in AJAX?

**SOLUTION NEEDED: We need the jQuery part for this. Urgent!**

on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JerryJones/PacTs/

Comment: You should add ids to all blocks as you saying "There are several Similar blocks".<br> Then with ajax show data in specific block.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$.post('ajax.php',function(data){

   // write your retrived data here 
   $(".editArea").html(data retrived);
  //or
    $(".editArea").val(data retrived);

}
```

Comment: Can you go through this updated question, please?

Comment: @JerryJones what the error are you getting ?

Comment: The content in the div(class="two") is not updating at all!
Seems there is some problem with the $(this) and .find() in the AJAX section.

Comment: @JerryJones because the parent of buttonSave is editBox not the main

Answer (score 0):

It'd be much easier if you gave the part where the content goes a unique ID.

You can then use onClick() on the button to call a JavaScript function:

```
function onEdit() {
    $("#EditBoxID".load('abc.php');
}

function onSave() {
    $("#ContentID").val($("#EditBoxID").val());
}
```

Comment: Can you go through this updated question, please?